# Getting the default(?) element of a jQuery() selection

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am sure there is a simple solution.

The starting scenario was the following.
I create a `<select>` element and populate it dynamycally:

```
function CreateDropDown(name, id, optionList)
{
    var combo = $("<select></select>").attr("id", id).attr("name", name);

    $.each(optionList, function (i, item) {
        combo.append("<option value='"+item.val+"'>" + item.el + "</option>");
    });

    return combo;
}
```

The aim was to extract the outerHTML. The following works right:

```
combo[0].outerHTML();
```

But I feel that indexing the array is very rough. At least in all that cases where the jQuery() function return a single element array.

**Question**

Whenever the jQuery() function return a single element array, is it possible to get the unique element **without array indexing**?

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/TF8gJ/)

Comment: take [`first()`](http://api.jquery.com/first/)? What exactly is `outerHTML()` - i don't know this one. Or do you mean the native js `outerHTML` (which is no function)?

Comment: Do you want the default selected element?  Or unique elements?

Comment: If by "the default element" you mean "the first element in the set", then `[0]` is just fine. What exactly is the issue?

Comment: `combo[0]` or `combo.get(0)` are both acceptable ways to get the wrapped DOM element.

Comment: Why do you use jQuery at all if your aim is just to generate an HTML string?

Comment: @Bergi: what do you suggest? Please answer with your solution. Anyway, I am lazy and I don't want to type all that keys using Javascript document.createElement ;)

Comment: @ADC: Just let `combo` be an HTML string instead of a DOM element (or even one wrapped in jQuery)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you "feel that indexing the array is very rough", you could write your own *nice* helper method. Something like a:

```
window.$$ = function(){
   return jQuery.apply(jQuery,arguments)[0];
}
```

*Usage:*

```
var combo = $$("<select></select>");
console.log( combo.outerHTML );
```

Answer (score 3):

jQuery objects are inherently collections of DOM objects, and there is no syntactic way to treat a jQuery object as wrapper around a single item.

jQuery documentation suggests using [get method](http://api.jquery.com/get/) to access individual DOM elements. It does not comment on performance difference between indexing operator and `.get()`, but it does say that "each jQuery object also masquerades as an array", so it would be ok to assume that indexing operator just adds another method call.

Answer (score 1):

Use `.get()` to get the html elements.

http://api.jquery.com/get/

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But combo.get() return an array as well. As commented by jbabey, I have to index it anyway.

Comment: If you just want the first element all the time you can use .first() or .get(0) or [0]. JQuery objects are just arrays of html elements.